# Rails 4 / Devise Force User to change password on first login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im having a weird issue trying to force my users to change their passwords on first login.

My server output is telling me it completed the patch successfully, however when I go to log back into the app its still the old password? I'll post output below.

But first here is my code to make this happen:

```
#application_controller.rb
      # Force PW Change On 1st Login
      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if current_user.sign_in_count == 1
          edit_passwords_path
        else
          authenticated_root_path
        end
      end



#passwords_controller.rb
  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    if current_user.update_without_password(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Password updated successfully."
      redirect_to authenticated_root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was a problem, please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end


#passwords form_for
<%= form_for current_user, url: passwords_path do |f| %>
  password:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br />
  password_confirmation:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#routes.rb
resource :passwords
```

The force password is doing everything it is supposed to except actually saving the new passwords.

my server output:

```
Started PATCH "/passwords" for ::1 at 2016-09-07 02:23:43 -0600
Processing by PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zUOrOdquBht6uwvjvBkPj2yaO0dCgL+3XGhKo0YV1+W/4rEEiiIRHwwOzRCqvSVeVkAO0M7c73ogcmgNQDq/DQ==", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update User"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-09-07 02:23:43 -0600
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/navigation/_unassigned.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/messages/_flash_msg.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 56ms (Views: 54.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Tangential: *why* do you need to force a change on first sign in? That sounds like a sign of bad security to me.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - not bad security. This is not a public facing app. Only and admin or suuperuser can create a new user. when the user is created a password is auto generated and emailed to the user, but then I want them to change it on first login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PasswordsController#Update change `update_without_password` to `update_with_password`:

```
  def update
    if current_user.update_with_password(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Password updated successfully."
      redirect_to authenticated_root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was a problem, please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Comment: So the problem was with devise registrations i needed to add the without_passwords method there and remove the current_password from params. Thanks for your assistance tho.